# Python 3.2.2 open('C:\file.txt') doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Admittedly, I am a novice; however, (I think) I did what the tutorial said (for the version I installed) and I can't get Python to read a file. Others have had problems with long file names or paths, but I kept mine short and sweet... so I thought. 
The file itself contains one word on a single line. 
The print('string') works, len('string') works...

Here's what I got, in IDLE and CMD, even before using the import statements included below:

> Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:07:29) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>
> > > import os, csv, urllib
> > >
> > > f0txt = ()
> > >
> > > f0txt = open("C:\try\in0.txt")
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "`<pyshell#4`>", line 1, in
>
> f0txt = open("C:\try\in0.txt")
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\try\in0.txt'

Answer (score 9):

`\` is an escape character. Try `open(r"C:\try\in0.txt")` or `open("C:\\try\\in0.txt")`.